# How to add data if the primary key is used as foreign key in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I am implementing a referral system in which a user can come form a reference of a previously registered user of my system or can register manually without any reference. The problem I am facing is that if the user is not using a reference token to register then the referee of the user is that user itself. How can I save the data (foreign key) of the user before getting the primary key of that row (that comes from auto increment method)? For more clearance I am attaching this image.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go is to auto generate the key before inserting instead of using the auto increment feature. The easiest way of doing this would be to define the ID columns as `uuid`s instead of `int`s and generate the next id from your application.

A better, though, IMHO, is to change your design, and instead of using the user as his own referral in case he wasn't referred  by another user just explicitly state he has no referral and use a `null` value there.